# use macro to copy a row into another worksheet if it meets a criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet in excel as below

```
1   apple   8/1/2013    8/2/2013    99373        11
2   apple   8/13/2013   8/3/2013    2626282    2121
3   berry   8/12/2013   8/4/2013    1289127     123
4   berry   8/15/2013   8/5/2013    12712671   1234
5   cherry  8/19/2013   8/6/2013    127127     3354
    apple   9/1/2013    9/5/2013    123456      200
    apple   9/2/2013    9/6/2013    246810      300
    berry   9/3/2013    9/7/2013    3691215     400
    berry   9/4/2013    9/8/2013    48121620    500
    cherry  9/5/2013    9/9/2013    510152025   600
    cherry  9/6/2013    9/10/2013   612182430   700
    apple   9/7/2013    9/11/2013   714212835   800
    berry   9/8/2013    9/12/2013   816243240   900
    berry   9/9/2013    9/13/2013   918273645   1000
    apple   9/10/2013   9/14/2013   10203040    1100
```

I am trying to get excel to copy every row that says either apple, berry, or cherry for the previous month (in this case - 9/1/13 - 9/30/13) and put them in the corresponding sheets. The sheet names are apple, berry and cherry. It then inserts a row and adds the row to the row after the last row with data. I also need it to generate the next number in the series in column a before copying it to the corresponding sheet. So row 6 would have the number 6 in column a.

I have tried some VBA code but I am having some trouble making it dynamic to search all the sheet names rather than just "apple". Also I am having trouble finding the last row with data. Please see below my code:

```
Sub testIt()
Dim r As Long, endRow As Long, pasteRowIndex As Long

endRow = 15
pasteRowIndex = 1

For r = 1 To endRow

    If Cells(r, Columns("B").Column).Value = "apple" Then


        Rows(r).Select
        Selection.Copy


        Sheets("apple").Select
        Rows(pasteRowIndex).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste


        pasteRowIndex = pasteRowIndex + 1



        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    End If
Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code so instead of copying rows 1 by 1, it auto-filters, copying the entire applicable range at once. Also, this assumes that any worksheet not named "Sheet1" will be used as search and copy criteria.

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Dim r As Long, c As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sFruit As String
Dim wsRow as Long

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
r = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 'find last row
c = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'find last column
Range("A1").AutoFilter
Range("C1:C" & r).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria2:=Array(1, "9/30/2013") 'filters for month of Sep'13

For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
        '*edited to accommodate pre-existing data
        ws.Activate '*activate sheet so you can use Cells() with it
        wsRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1 '*find first usable row in ws
        sFruit = ws.Name 'criteria to look for
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate 'bring focus back to main sheet
        Range("B1:B" & r).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=sFruit
        Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(r, c)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ws.Range("A" & wsRow)
    End If
Next ws

Range("A1").AutoFilter

Application.CutCopyMode = True
```

You can add functionality to filter by dates.  I would suggest recording yourself using auto-filter so you can get an idea on how to modify the code.

Comment: What if I had data in the "apple" sheet and wanted to insert a new row where the data from sheet1 would be added to this?

Comment: See my edit above. You need to add the last row formula inside the IF clause - when the worksheet meets the criteria, a new final row needs to be determined specific to that sheet. This last row is then used in the Range(...).Copy (destination) portion.

Comment: One last question, do you know how to search only the date of the previous month (9/1/13 - 9/30/13)?

Comment: You would copy the same AutoFilter procedure in the IF portion, but modify it to your column and criteria. Example: `Range("C1:C" & r).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria2:=Array(1, "9/30/2013")` would filter column C for all of September 2013. You would be okay placing this outside of the For...Next and If...Then constructs if all of your criteria are looking for the same month.